# Example of transfer function and driving signal equation

Tags: electrical-engineering, signal-processing, complex-systems, linear-systems

In a text I am using it states that for linear dynamical systems, there is a very simple relationship between the power spectrum of the driving signal and that of any one of the system variables. If the power spectrum of the driving signal is $S(\omega)$, and that of a system variable $x$ is $X_{S}(\omega)$, then $$X_{S}(\omega) = |G_{x}(\omega)|^2S(\omega)$$ where $G_{x}(\omega)$ is called the transfer function for the system variable $x$.

**Question:** Does anyone know what a good definition of "driving signal" would be and is there a simple example which uses this equation?

Comment: This is weird, because it means that no phase of transfer function is considered, there is usually a complex part. It means that there is no time delay of the output signal in this case. Are you sure that the definition is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to look at this.  $S\left( \omega \right)$ is the external signal, e.g., something produced by nature like the visible light from the sun.  It is a function of frequency, $\omega$, because it's not a constant (just like the [solar spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight)).  $X_{s}\left( \omega \right)$ is the signal received/measured by the instrument/detector.  The [transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function), $G_{x}\left( \omega \right)$, is also called the [response function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response), which is, in experimental practice, an attempt to model the difference between input and output signals.

An example is a wire [dipole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna).  Even if we supply a perfectly flat spectrum (i.e., [white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise)), the output by the antenna will not send a flat spectrum signal to the electronics.  One then uses the difference between the known input signal (white noise) and output signal (observation) to determine the form of $G_{x}\left( \omega \right)$.  In some cases, this can be done analytically, e.g., $G_{x}\left( \omega \right)$ is related to the complex impedance for an [RLC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit).

> Does anyone know what a good definition of "driving signal" would be and is there a simple example which uses this equation?

Nearly all electromagnetic sensors, whether dipole antenna, [camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_transfer_function), or a human [eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_sensitivity), have a frequency response function that can be approximated by $X_{s}\left( \omega \right) = \lvert G_{x}\left( \omega \right) \rvert^{2} \ S\left( \omega \right)$.  There are no perfect detectors.

Answer (score 0):

The driving signal is simply the input signal to the system.

In the context of signal theory, this falls under linear systems theory. This is applicable for any linear system. The typical example of such a linear system is a filter.